# Stretch a Border inside Button

Tags: flutter

I want to make a button with two rounded borders inside each other.
It should look like this

[image]

But currently it looks like this

[image]

I tried to set a `BoxDecoration` to a `Container` and tried to expand the Container with `Expanded` or `SizedBox.expand` but it just doesn't stretch

```
return FittedBox(
  child: RaisedButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
    onPressed: () {},
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 3)
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
      child: Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: Text("Text"),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 3),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Is there a better way to do draw a border inside a button?

Comment: add `alignment: Alignment.center` property to Container, both answers below are weird

Comment: Hey, please check the below answer, and let the user know whether which one helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GestureDetector flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to get the button work, and use

- `Container()`
- `Center()`

to achieve your aforementioned design. Also, read about [BoxDecoration class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html). It will help you in great extent. Rest you will get to know from the below code itself.

**Code**

```
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print('Hello'),
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                // play with width to get the width of the border
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 5.0),
                // play with blurRadius, and offset for the shadow
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 9.0, offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0))]
              ),
              child: Container(
                // play with margin for inside border
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                  // play with width to get the width of the border
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 5.0)
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Text', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                )
              )
            )
          )
```

**Result**

[image: Resultant Image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `FittedBox` and wrap the inner `Container` with a `SizedBox.expand`:

```
RaisedButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                onPressed: () {},
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 3)),
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    child: SizedBox.expand(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Center(child: Text("Text")),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 3),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )))
```

Result:

[image: img]